# Syntax Error on when adding variable in argument

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to add content of a json file into the folder creds.json. However, I am getting a s**yntax error : EOL while scanning string literal**. Please advise!

```
dbutils.fs.put("/user1/creds.json", "{"type": "service_account"}")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dbutils.fs.put("/user1/creds.json", '{"type": "service_account"}')
```

Comment: You sure? That definitely fixes an error. If you still see an error, you have other problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a quote *in* the string *and* to indicate the beginning and end of the string, for obvious reasons.

You could switch the outer quotes to single quotes, escape the inner quotes, or just use triple quotes.

```
dbutils.fs.put("/user1/creds.json", """{"type": "service_account"}""")
```